# Read Java Application.conf in C#

Tags: java, c#, .net, config, application.conf

There is an existing java project which has an application.conf file which looks like this:

```
general{
  name="prod2"
}

system {
  type=2
}

db {
  connection="jdbc:sqlite::memory:"
  dropTable=false
}
```

Are there any libraries in .NET which parse these Java config files. As its not any standard that i recognize. I havent been able to find any.

Comment: Looks like [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this format is called HOCON (Human-Optimized Config Object Notation)

There are a few nuget packages out there that parse this. I used this one. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hocon/1.0.0